# Create df using pandas, split column names into new columns, add new rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new Python but i'm trying to make my dataframe using Pandas and format a little different.
Im trying to make it so that every time there is a column that starts with "Bot" it adds a new row
to the data frame but keeps the first 2 columns data. i also need to split the column that starts with Top into 3 more columns. here is what the data comes through as:

| Job | Lot | Top (16-t-3) | Bot | Top (15-s-4) | Bot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job 1 | Lot A | 127.3 | 126.5 | 127.2 | 128.5 |
| Job 2 | Lot B | 127.8 | 127.8 | 125.7 | 124.5 |

And this is what i would like

| Job | Lot | Layer | T-s | Circ | Top | Bot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Job 1 | Lot A | 16 | t | 3 | 127.3 | 126.5 |
| Job 1 | Lot A | 15 | s | 4 | 127.2 | 128.5 |
| Job 2 | Lot B | 16 | t | 3 | 127.8 | 127.8 |
| Job 2 | Lot B | 15 | s | 4 | 125.7 | 124.5 |

all of the data is saved as a CSV

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('xxx.CSV')
print(df)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working pipeline:

```
(df.set_index(['Job', 'Lot'])
   .T
   .set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[c.split(' ')[1] for c in  df.set_index(['Job', 'Lot']).columns if ' ' in c],
                                          ['Top', 'Bot']
                                         ])
              )
   .T
   .stack(level=0)
   .reset_index()
   .pipe(lambda d: d.join((d['level_2']
                            .str.strip('()')
                            .str.split('-', expand=True)
                            .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(['Layer', 'T-s', 'Circ'])))
                           )))
   .drop('level_2', axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
      Job     Lot    Bot    Top Layer T-s Circ
0  Job 1   Lot A   128.5  127.2    15   s    4
1  Job 1   Lot A   126.5  127.3    16   t    3
2  Job 2   Lot B   124.5  125.7    15   s    4
3  Job 2   Lot B   127.8  127.8    16   t    3
```